# Alternative to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, sapui5

I have a sapui5 table and I have called a scroll function on the tables scrollbar. It works only when I use `setTimeout`. I am assuming that's because the data in the table loads slightly after the actually table loads.

Here's the code I have:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var lastScroll = 0;
    $("#__xmlview0--players-vsb-sb").scroll(function () {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScroll) {
            console.log("scrolling down");
        } else {
           console.log("scrolling up");
        }
        lastScroll = st;
    });
}, 900);
```

I have tried to use the `onAfterRendering` function as an alternative but I can't get that to work. Does anyone know an alternative to `setTimeout`?

Here is my [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/fisane/edit?html,console,output).

Comment: What do you mean by "..to allow the table to load first."   Do you mean for page load?  If so then you should be using $( document ).ready(... instead (or similar).  This probably isn't what is causing your issue here but something to consider.

Comment: Second JSbin seems to be working fine

Comment: @nurdyguy I've tried `$(document).ready` it doesn't work. @leo.fcx It does work fine. The only thing is that it doesn't work when I use the mouse wheel which I was testing it with, why I don't know. Any reason why it doesn't work properly with the mouse wheel?

Comment: Is there other DOM manipulation happening on the page?

Comment: Yes. You can view my code by clicking on the JSBin in the question.

Comment: Well, document ready wont work if your content loads dinamically. You should add a CALLBACK to the function that loads the data of your table, when x is done, do z

Comment: I've done some research on callback functions and I am still unsure as to where to put it in my code. The function that loads by data is: `var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel( {
      data: player
  });
  oView.setModel(oModel);`. Do I put it somewhere in here?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a sap.m.Table you can use the updateFinished Event from sap.m.ListBase see : 
[OpenUI5 SDK - Demo Kit v2.0](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html)

```
updateFinished(oControlEvent)
This event is called after items binding and afterwards related DOM is updated.
Parameters:
{sap.ui.base.Event} oControlEvent
{sap.ui.base.EventProvider} oControlEvent.getSource
{object}    oControlEvent.getParameters
{string}    oControlEvent.getParameters.reason  The reason of update. Possible values are "Binding", "Filter", "Sort", "Growing", "Change", "Refresh", "Context"
{int}   oControlEvent.getParameters.actual  Actual number of items.
{int}   oControlEvent.getParameters.total   The total count of bound items. This parameter can be used if "growing" feature is enabled.
Since:
1.16.3
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.